# What are the differences between using OLEDB and ODP.NET to connect to an Oracle database?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oledb, odp.net

I have two small VB.NET applications that connect to the same Oracle database.  One uses the OLEDB provider, and the other uses Oracle's ODP.NET.  Should I expect to see problems with the OLEDB provider, as it's less 'native' to Oracle?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB was designed for accessing generic databases, ODP.NET is native Oracle provider which should have better performance and allows to use specific Oracle features.

Comment: More details here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-089115.html